# The dots don't line up with the background

Tags: bug, design

Well, since there are looking to change some things with the design, I thought this would be a good time to bring this up.

Has anyone noticed that the dot-patterns don't line up?

[image]

If the new design has the dots, can they line up, or if it doesn’t include the dots - that would be problem solved too.

What would be even cooler, is if the dot background stayed stationary when scrolling.

Comment: I'm in talks with Canonical right now. We're going to do some design tweaks on Ask Ubuntu to reflect their main site design. I'll fix this when the new design launches here.